# Exchange 2007 Client for Linux

Tags: linux, exchange, exchange-2007

Has anyone had success with a working Exchange 2007 client for Linux?
I'm not looking for an IMAP client or anything of the sort...there's plenty of them around, but a client that actually supports the exchange 2007 protocol.
I've tried Open Change MAPI to no success, I'm unsure if this is because I'm doing it wrong or because of our external hosts strange multi-client setup.

Does anyone have any working experience with any?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bad news is that there isn't any decent Exchange clients for Linux, other than possibly some crap connector for Evolution that will only compile on Suse.

The good news is that starting with Exchange 2007, there is a SOAP web-services interface for Exchange, so it's now feasible for somebody to actually write a client, which wasn't the case with MAPI. Microsoft is updating its Mac email client and Apple is providing native support with Snow Leopard, so something should pop up one of these days.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortuantely there are not many options out there for Linux, most people I know running Linux with Exchange have to either rely on a VM running Outlook, or resort to IMAP.

There are only two projects I know of that are working in this area:

- [Open Change MAPI](http://www.openchange.org/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=63&Itemid=71), which you've already looked at
- [Evolution MAPI](http://www.go-evolution.org/MAPI_FAQ) - The successor to the previous Evolution Exchange component that scraped OWA.

Answer (score 1):

Im using Evolution with the Exchange Connector in Mandriva 2009, the packages are:

- evolution-mapi-0.26.2-1mdv2009.1
- evolution-2.26.3-1.1mdv2009.1
- evolution-exchange-2.26.1-1mdv2009.1
- evolution-data-server-2.26.3-1.1mdv2009.1

It works with the MAPI native protocol but its extremely slow! Its not usable, so Im still using OWA and waiting for a solution :(

Comment: DavMail is a POP/IMAP/SMTP/Caldav/Carddav/LDAP exchange gateway allowing users to use any mail/calendar client, Im using it with Kmail and it works like a charm  http://davmail.sourceforge.net   (I found this solution 1 year ago, I forgot to update this, sorry :(  but I hope this helps)

Answer (score 1):

Try This: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1237875

Its a howto setup thunderbird and DavMail to work with exchange 2007 email, calendars, tasks and contacts.

I use this setup and it works very well.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite a native client, but you could use Web access instead. The 2007 version of Outlook Web Access is very much like the client itself.

Comment: The 2007 version of OWA is very much like Outlook IF you are using IE. A non-IE browser gets a reduced feature set. Apparently Exchange 2010 will support the "premium" OWA interface on non-IE browsers.

Answer (score 0):

[Evolution](http://projects.gnome.org/evolution/) connecting via the Exchange Connector on Ubuntu *might* work.  However, I'm still waiting on our Exchange admin to get OWA up and going (a prerequisite, as it doesn't do native MAPI).  So I'm afraid that I can't confirm this as "working".  But it's been known to work with Exchange 2000/2003 for some time now.  And yes, those are with OWA, not MAPI.

Comment: OWA on Exchange 2007 works out-of-the-box, and making it usable from outside your network only requires standard HTTPS. Your Exchange admin doesn't seem to be exactly the best one around...

Comment: It's a department policy.  IIS services are not allowed to be directly exposed to the outside world without a proxy present.  In addition to that, there was a decision to not have OWA initially enabled as it was deemed unnecessary.  These decisions are not always in the hands of the tech staff.  Sometimes, it's not the admin - sometimes, it's just the way things are.  (and no, I'm not the admin being mentioned)

Answer (score 0):

OWA wont support personal folders, just an fyi.